# Symmetric relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A=\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ is $ B = \{ (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 1) \} $

Is $B$ a symmetric relation on $A$?

I said no because not all $x, y \in A$ are in $B$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

No, $B$ is a symmetric relation on $A$, because since if $(a,b) \in B$ then $(b,a) \in B$.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of symmetric relation does not really require us to have any $A$ to begin with.

We say that $R$ is a symmetric relation if the following holds: Whenever an ordered pair $(a,b)\in R$ then the reversed pair, $(b,a)\in R$ as well.

Symmetry, as well as transitivity, are internal properties of a relation (in contrast of "reflexivity" which is indeed external).

Finally, note that under your "definition" the only symmetric relation on $A$ would be $A\times A$. That's not a very interesting property now, is it?

Comment: Thanks, this makes it very clear.

Comment: I think the meaning of the question, even if the OP didn't know it (and I think chances are he did!), actually is whether $\;B\;$ is even a relation on $\;A\;$...and imo for example, it is not since it is *not* defined on $\;A\;$ but on a proper subset of it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The definition is that $R$ is a relation on a set $X$ when $R\subseteq X\times X$. In this case $B$ is certainly a subset of $A\times A$, and so it is a relation on $A$, and incidentally it is also a symmetric relation.

Comment: I see ,@AsafKaragila, thanks. Yet I'd rather do here as I usually do when dealing with functions (a kind of special relations), and try to "compactize" (?!) the definition domain to what it acually is. Thus, we could always say that $\;\log:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;$ , but **in fact** we know it must be $\;\log: (0,\infty)\to\Bbb R\;$ (real functions all the time), and in case the domain can't be determined/is unknown then it should be so specified. I really don't know if my stance is standard, or even important, but that's what I think.